# BasicAuthentication for WebChromeClient

Tags: android

Using WebViewClient, I used following code to for BasicAuthentication:

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                              HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

            handler.proceed("test_user", "test_password");

        }

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Now I am using `WebChromeClient` as:

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    });
```

How do I do BasicAuthentication in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                          HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

        handler.proceed("test_user", "test_password");

    }

    //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(url);
```